# Does Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS include an SSH server by default?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ssh, openssh

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985375/does-ubuntu-desktop-enable-remote-ssh-access-by-default) answer, SSH is disabled by default. However, looking around at tutorials, there were [plenty](http://linux-sys-adm.com/ubuntu-16.04-lts-how-to-install-and-configure-ssh/) of examples of installing an SSH server (e.g. `sudo apt install openssh-server`), which I completed. After running the install (appropriate prompts for new data usage etc.), I checked the aforementioned post and found the file `/etc/init/ssh.conf` did indeed exist.

Did I just install OpenSSH for no reason, and did 16.04.4 LTS have an SSH server built in that I simply had to enable and configure?

Comment: Please stop using non-relieable third-party information sources and use official [description from Ubuntu Server Guide p.101](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf).

Comment: Why should /etc/init/ssh.conf not be there **after the installation**. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @N0rbert This is not a server installation.

Comment: @Bruni Good point. I feel sheepish...

Comment: @downvoter, it would be courteous to explain your rationale so I may improve questions in the future...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH server is provided by the `openssh-server` package.
You can consult with [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server Guide p.101](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) about setting it up.

**Desktop flavors** of Ubuntu do NOT include that package when installed.

The **Ubuntu Server** and **Ubuntu Core** flavors DO include the package, since they are designed to run headless.

Any flavor of Ubuntu can install (or uninstall) the package. Any flavor of Ubuntu can have (or not) an SSH server.

Comment: You answered my question when you said `*Desktop flavors* of Ubuntu do not include that package when installed.` After browsing the server guide, I see that it does have useful information, but I would not presume to read such a guide originally, as I’m not using Ubuntu server version.